# 1099 to an S Corporation

Tags: united-states, s-corporation, form-1099

I am a physician and a sole owner of my business as a S corp. I had another job which I earned money on a 1099 to my SS number. Can I 1099 the money to my business?

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. **You** had another job for which **you** earned money. What does the corporation have to do with it?

Corporation is a separate entity from your person, and since it was in no way involved in the transaction - there's no justification to funnel money through it. Doing so may pierce the corporate veil and expose you to liability which you created the corporation to shield yourself from. Not to mention the tax evasion, which is the reason you are asking the question to begin with....